# How to create more than one mean coordinate in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, point

I have a point shapefile with several thousands of points in it.

I've split the points up into spatial groups using a vectorgrid and pointcount.

I wish to create a mean coordinate for each group of points. However, where there are more than 200 points in each group, I wish to add two new points that are evenly distributed amongst the group.

Is it possible to create two or more new points using the 'mean coordinates' tool in QGIS?

Further issues i'm having with this method:

- How do I get my new point (generated by the mean coordinate) to 'snap' ontop of a pre-existing point
- Groups are created based on their pointcount. Where I have two groups of points that are spatially apart, yet with the same pointcount, each point is placed in the same group - is there a way to alter this - perhaps with a weighted mean?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A script in WhiteboxGIS solves the problem of creating multiple mean coordinates and can be found in this thread: [How to calculate mean coordinates from big point datasets?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71734/how-to-calculate-mean-coordinates-from-big-point-datasets)